# How do I add an action listener to a static Jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, static, jbutton, actionlistener

I need to call the homeIcons method in another class statically but I don't know how to add the action listener to the static button. Is there a way to do this simply? I need to use this panel in a CardLayout to refresh a frame. The Buttons change the panel in the CardLayout, so I need the action listeners to work.

Need to add this panel to add to a CardLayout

```
public class Home extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    //fields
    private static JButton sandwich;
    private static JButton burger;
    private static JButton pancake;
    private static JButton ramen;
    private static JButton beefWellington;
    private static JButton help;
    private static JPanel homeBody;

public static JPanel homeIcons() {
        JPanel topButtons = new JPanel();
        GridLayout topLayout = new GridLayout(1,2);
        topButtons.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,120,0,120));
        topLayout.setVgap(5);
        topLayout.setHgap(150);
        topButtons.setLayout(topLayout);
        topButtons.setBackground(new Color(200,200,200));
        
        //Level 1, make a sandwich
        ImageIcon sandwichImage = new ImageIcon("Resources/sandwichthumbnail.png");
        sandwich = new JButton();
        sandwich.setIcon(sandwichImage);
        sandwich.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        sandwich.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        sandwich.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(sandwich);
        topButtons.add(sandwich);
        
        //Level 2, make a burger
        ImageIcon burgerImage = new ImageIcon("Resources/burgerthumbnail.png");
        burger = new JButton();
        burger.setIcon(burgerImage);
        burger.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        burger.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        burger.addActionListener(this);;
        this.add(burger);
        topButtons.add(burger);
        
        JPanel lowerButtons = new JPanel();
        GridLayout lowerLayout = new GridLayout(1,2);
        lowerButtons.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,15,0,15));
        lowerLayout.setVgap(5);
        lowerLayout.setHgap(5);
        lowerButtons.setLayout(lowerLayout);
        lowerButtons.setBackground(new Color(200,200,200));
        
        //Level 3, make a souffle pancake
        ImageIcon pancakeImage = new ImageIcon("Resources/pancakethumbnail.png");
        pancake = new JButton();
        pancake.setIcon(pancakeImage);
        pancake.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        pancake.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pancake.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(pancake);
        lowerButtons.add(pancake);
        
        //Level 4, 
        ImageIcon ramenImage = new ImageIcon("Resources/ramenthumbnail.png");
        ramen = new JButton();
        ramen.setIcon(ramenImage);
        ramen.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        ramen.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        ramen.addActionListener(this);;
        this.add(ramen);
        lowerButtons.add(ramen);
        
        ImageIcon wellingtonImage = new ImageIcon("Resources/wellingtonthumbnail.png");
        beefWellington = new JButton();
        beefWellington.setIcon(wellingtonImage);
        beefWellington.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        beefWellington.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        beefWellington.addActionListener(this);;
        this.add(beefWellington);
        lowerButtons.add(beefWellington);
        
        homeBody.add(lowerButtons);
        homeBody.add(topButtons);
        return homeBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do the buttons need to be static?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I changed them to static to resolve the error making static reference to nonstatic object

Comment: I see... So then my question is - why is the method static where you're referring to those buttons?

Comment: @OneCricketeer a jbutton in another class calls the method statically. So I made the method static too comply

Comment: That's fine, but I suggest you don't make that a static method of a JFrame subclass that implements ActionListener itself... Rather you could make a standalone `class ButtonFactory { public static JPanel getHomePanel() {} }`, and this way it'd be more concrete where the error is

Comment: Do not extend `JFrame`.  It's bad practice.  Extend `JPanel` and add to an instance of `JFrame`.  And where is the homeBody JPanel instantiated?

Comment: Your buttons are not static at all. Only the references (variables) can be static. Add listeners just like you would to any other buttons.

Comment: `static` is not your friend (in this context), you should make the effort to learn to live without it

Answer (score 0):

While I question the code layout choice, you could pass though parameters for each button action listener, assuming you need the context provided from the calling method

Note: within a static method, there's no `this`

```
static JPanel homeIcons(ActionListener sandwichAction) {
    JPanel topButtons = new JPanel();

    JButton sandwich = new JButton();
    sandwich.addActionListener(sandwichAction);

    topButtons.add(sandwich);
    
    return topButtons;
}
```

Otherwise, inline `new ActionListener()` into the button method itself

Answer (score 0):

Other than there can't be **this** in static context. You can implement each as:

```
sandwich.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //action listener here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate code, each segment of which has a few common requirements.  You should make a general method for each button.  Something like this.  You may need to adjust a few things since this is out of context of your actual code.

```
 
public  JButton createButton(String imagePath, ActionListener buttonListener) { 
        ImageIcon foodImage = new ImageIcon(imagePath);
        foodButton = new JButton();
        foodButton.setIcon(foodImage);
        foodButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        foodButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        foodButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        this.add(foodButton);  // <--- not certain what "this" is??
        lowerButtons.add(foodButton); // <-- might be best to add upon return
        return foodButton;
}
```

You may need to add the button upon return from this method.  You may even be able to make this method static if you don't need to reference any instance fields.

And regarding declaring you buttons static (which I would not do).  Just because something is `static` does not mean it cannot hold an `instance` of something else (like an actionListener).  It can just make it more difficult.  Especially if the enclosing class implements a common actionListener.  That precludes being able to reference the listener via `this`.